# Отображение ForeignKey в админ панели django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Есть некоторая модель, другая использует ее в качестве Foreign Key (связь одно к многим), подскажите пожалуйста как отобразить эту связь в админ-панели первой модели?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: Большое спасибо!